# Shaving on Rosh Chodesh when it is Erev Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, hair, rosh-chodesh-new-month, rabbi-yehudah-hechasid

Is one who has the minhag of Reb Yehuda Hachassid to not shave or take a haircut on rosh chodesh (as outlined in [his will](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19500&st=&pgnum=28)) allowed to shave and or take haircuts when Rosh Chodesh comes out on Erev Shabbos?

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35221

Answer (score 3):

The Mishna Berurah ([OC 260 end of sk 7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=63) quoting the [Magen Avraham 260 sk 0](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14211&st=&pgnum=36)) says that those who follow the Will of Rabbi Yehuda HaChasid do not trim their fingernails of take haircuts on Rosh Chodesh even if it is on Friday.

Comment: Is anyone aware of  other opinions?

Comment: Double AA, he doesn't say everyone who follows _RY hachasid_ doesn't shave on Friday _rosh chodesh_. He only says some, following _RY hachasid_, don't shave on Friday _rosh chodesh_. That doesn't mean there aren't those who follow _RY hachasid_ and shave Friday _rosh chodesh_.

Comment: @msh210 Logically correct, but I think you may be reading too closely. Certainly I would now say the burden of proof is on the other side.

Comment: Why is it a sakana